# Wordpress Twenty Ten Theme

Tags: wordpress

Wondering if anybody knows a way to edit the actual HTML framework of the default Twenty Ten Wordpress theme, or if there is a way to add a div to it through the php files. I would like to customize it so that the header_area is the full width of the page and on the top of the page, so I wanted to ask here to see if y'all would know the answer.

Thanks!

jwinton

Comment: Have you tried looking at the files in your `wp-content/themes` directory? They're all there.

Comment: Yes. What is the HTML file that I should edit?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done both through the Dashboard or by using a normal text editor. Some themes have specific admin controls for changing the look/feel of the headers and other areas. I vaguely remember 2010 having some of these options.

I *strongly* recommend making these sorts of changes in a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), rather than editing the 2010 files directly.